# How can I get NSIS welcome page to appear

Tags: nsis

I cannot get my welcome page (or finished page) to appear in an NSIS installer.

Other pages appear fine.  I've even compiled and run [WelcomeFinish.nsi](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/Modern%20UI/WelcomeFinish.nsi) with the same result.

I am running Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: Did you do a full install of NSIS? Are you using MUI(1) or MUI2?

Comment: Yes it was a full install. I've tried both mui and mui2. I've also tried the latest 2.x and 3.x releases.

Comment: When I installed NSIS on a different computer (32 bit Windows 7), I noticed that even the NSIS welcome page doesn't show up on my main system.  Now to track down that cause.  (It could be McAfee, even though I've disabled it.) I'll post back with results.  Suggestions are still appreciated.

Comment: Yes that sounds plausible, the Welcome and Finish pages are custom pages and use a plugin...

Comment: McAfee is blocking the plugin.  I'm going to try putting my welcome message in as the license to see if that works.  It would be nice if the modern UI were part of the base .EXE file.

Comment: Submit a false positive sample @ https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB67411 virustotal.com is not complaining, which NSIS version are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51836/discussion-between-brad-bruce-and-anders)

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to uninstall McAfee but as a workaround you can try this:

```
Function .onInit
UnsafeStrCpy $pluginsdir "$LocalAppData\MyCompany\Temp" ; NSIS v3+
CreateDirectory $pluginsdir
FunctionEnd
```